# How does the Perl Template::Declare modul work in terms of Perl language syntax?

Tags: xml, perl, syntax

I need to create really complex XML documents (METS), using prefixes, namespaces, schema validation, document-internally referenced element IDs, attributes from mixed namespaces... pretty much everything XML allows you to do. Also there will be loads of heavily nested elements, making it difficult to track starting- and ending-tags manually.

Researching several possibilities to do that I came across [`Template::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Declare).

The [synopsis](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Declare#SYNOPSIS) provides an example that I show here for reference:

```
template simple => sub {
        html {
            head {}
            body {
                p { 'Hello, world wide web!' }
            }
        }
    };
```

My question is: what is happening here in terms of Perl language elements? How does this translate to valid Perl syntax? For example, what are the "html", "head" keywords etc. here representing for the Perl compiler? Is that some implicit sub declaration? Perl does (or allows you to do) so many things implicitly that I never know what is actually happening. I don't want to just copy and paste some example and hope that I can bend it to do what I need, I'd actually like to know what I'm doing...

Can someone enlighten me here?

Comment: As a sidenote, I would not use Template::Declare for large XML documents. Use XML::Twig or XML::Compile instead. This thing will kill you later when you have to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks simbabque, I'll have a look at those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty of CPAN is that you can just take a look at the code. This one is a bit complicated I admit, but here is what you are looking for:

https://metacpan.org/source/ALEXMV/Template-Declare-0.46/lib/Template/Declare/Tags.pm#L525

Basically the sugary syntax comes from the [prototype](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) `&`, which tells Perl that the sub is accepting a code reference. The `{ ... }` here are not hashes, they are blocks, the same as the ones in a `map` or `grep`. In your example, they are chained together.

Because of the prototype, you can ommit parenthesis and commas, but you could also write the example like this:

```
template simple => sub {
  html(
    sub {
      head(
        sub { },
        body(
          sub {
            p( sub { 'Hello, world wide web!' } );
          } ) );
    } );
};
```

The way this is implemented, if written out directly, would be:

```
sub template(%) { ... } # the % tells it to expect a hash
sub html(&) { ... }
sub head(&) { ... }
sub body(&) { ... }
sub p(&) { ... }
```

This kind of stuff is called [Syntactic Sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), or a [DSL (Domain-Specific Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

Note that **you should only use prototypes in your code if you know what you are doing**! Chances are, you do not want them.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! But I'm still confused: How are those subs named "html", "head" etc. miraculously defined? For xml I could use any tag name so they can't be predeclared. I'm also confused by the usage of {} as hash in the sub template(%) and then used as block delimiters in the other subs. Is all this just some fancy way of building a big hash?

Comment: There is no hash. Those are blocks. Look at the code I linked. There is `_install()`, which is defined at https://metacpan.org/source/ALEXMV/Template-Declare-0.46/lib/Template/Declare/Tags.pm#L86. It takes a target namespace, a coderef and a name for it and imports the function in that namespace. It's called for each of the tags defined in the TagSet. I guess you would have to either write a TagSet or find how it deals with arbitrary ones in the documentation. A quick glance did not yield that info for me.

Comment: Thanks again simbabque. Since I'm new to Perl, I didn't see much point in trying to parse the code for something so intricate... maybe one day when I feel like Perl has become second nature :). Here's an example how someone uses it with arbitrary tags: http://justatheory.com/computers/programming/perl/xml-generation.html . There's something about TagSet but I don't really understand it in detail.

Comment: He's defining a TagSet and using it. But again, this is probably not what you are looking for. The post is from 2009. The guy is acclaimed, but still it is 4 years old. If you have all kinds of fancy XML stuff (which is a nice way of saying overly complicated), you might have a DTD. Which means you can use XML::Compile very comfortably.

Comment: no dtd but several schemas. Anyway, after checking out several possibilities, including your suggestions above, I decided to go with the sledgehammer solution and simply create template files and do lots of string building and replacing ;) I can't see any great advantage in doing this the "correct" way when simple string ops give me the same result. Unless I'm missing something fundamental here.